# Magento Vs Magneto

Tags: discussion, suggestion

Lately, i am seeing in Magento stack exchange that, Some question's descriptions are having the following commands with the spelling of Magento and Magneto.

1. [bin/magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=bin%2Fmagento)
2. [bin/magneto](https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=bin%2Fmagneto)

Comment: There is nothing wrong ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a good question.

Maybe the user does not intentionally do this mistake.
So, we should correct this spelling mistake. Let do it.

Comment: Ok, ill edit that questions, thank you. I just checked this. Now the results are not appearing with bin/magneto. What a fast response dear. Good

Answer (score 1):

@Teja bhagavan Kollepara its not only about commands ... you fix nearly every "magneto" typo. So keep on ... :P

(I only disagree with some of your removals of "thank you" lines ... it doesnt hurt and saying THX isnt normal today anymore ... so pls keep them.)

Comment: Yes. Thanks for update. Yeah i have understand the way of editing bro. Thanks